# Goodness of fit of a distribution obtained by minimizing a log-loss function

Tags: maximum-likelihood, survival, goodness-of-fit, lognormal-distribution, censoring

I am trying to fit a log-normal distribution to a time-to-failure data of a product, but the data to which I want to fit the distribution is not regular data. In the data, every row $i$ has two pieces of information about the time to failure.

1. The time($t_i$) for which the item $i$ was observed.
2. A binary variable $y_i\in \{0,1\}$ indicating whether the item had failed before time $t_i$ (1 if failed, 0 otherwise).

So, the data looks something like this.

| Observed Time($t_i$) | failed ? ($y_i$) |
| --- | --- |
| 5 hrs | 1 |
| 6 hrs | 0 |
| 5 hrs | 0 |
| 7 hrs | 1 |

**I emphasize that the time $t_i$ is not the actual failure time. If item $i$ fails ($y_i=1$), $t_i$ is just an upper limit of the failure time. If $i$ doesn't fail ($y_i=0$) then $t_i$ is the lower limit of the failure time.**

Now, if we assume all the items are identical and their time to failure is a random variable $\hat t$ that follows a log-normal distribution with parameters $\alpha = (\mu.\sigma)$, then the probability that product $i$ would fail before observation time $t_i$ is $p_i = \Pr(\hat t<t_i) = F(t_i; \mu, \sigma)$ where$F(.)$ is the CDF of log-normal distribution.

So, for every observation $i$, using the probability of failure $p_i$ and the actual label ($y_i$) denoting whether the product failed, we can construct a log-likelihood function like this
$$y_i \ln(p_i) + (1-y_i)\ln(1-p_i) = y_i \ln(F(t_i; \mu, \sigma)) + (1-y_i)\ln(1-F(t_i; \mu, \sigma))$$
**Note**: This is simlar to loss function of a binary logistic regression

We can define the log-loss for the whole data ($n$ datapoints) as
$$-\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \ln(F(t_i; \mu, \sigma)) + (1-y_i)\ln(1-F(t_i; \mu, \sigma))$$

We can minimize this loss-function over $\mu, \sigma$ and get the estimate of $\mu, \sigma$.

But after finding $\mu, \sigma$, how do I know that the log-normal distribution is a good fit? I don't have the actual values of the observations to do something like a **KS test**

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding: the times $t_i$ for items  having $y_i=1$ are not the actual failure times, but just an upper limit to the actual failure time?

Comment: @EdM Exactly. you are right.

Comment: Edited my question to emphasize this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is double censoring. You only have an upper limit to the failure times for items with $y_i=1$ (left censored) and a lower limit for those with $y_i=0$ (right censored).

Although you don't have exact failure times, you still can get a nonparametric estimate of the survival curve $S(t)=1-F(t)$ against which to compare your lognormal model. Turnbull proposed an iterative approach in the [Journal of the American Statistical Association 69: 169-173 (1974)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2285518) that takes advantage of the information provided by both the left-censored and right-censored cases, as well as any having known event times.

I don't work with such data, but you can try the tools provided by the [interval](https://cran.r-project.org/package=interval) and [icenReg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=icenReg) packages in R. Although the names of the packages suggest that they are for interval-censored data (for which you know a time interval during which the event occurred), [these notes](http://dmrocke.ucdavis.edu/Class/BST222.2021.Fall/Lecture11_Interval_Double_Censoring_.pdf) point out:

> Double censored data have some observations left censored, some right censored, and some exact. In a way, this is a subset of interval censored data with the left side of the interval for left-censored observations and the right side of the interval for right-censored observations written as NA or ±Inf.

With that data coding you can use software for interval-censored data to get a nonparametric survival curve, if you don't want to implement the Turnbull method yourself. Those notes illustrate that approach with data from the text by [Klein and Moeschberger](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953991), maybe the best source for explaining how to deal with all combinations of truncation and censoring in survival analysis.